# Nginx + Ubuntu 9.10, gzip not functioning

Tags: web-server, nginx, gzip

So I installed and configured Nginx 0.7.62 on a new Slicehost Ubuntu 9.10 slice.

All seems to work fine with the server, except that gzip isn't working for one reason or another. I made sure that it's setting were correct in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 3;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush on;

    keepalive_timeout 2;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This normally wouldn't be a big deal, but gzip support could save considerable bandwidth for my site. Does anyone have any ideas of what to check, or has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: How were you testing that the compression was working? If you are using one of the many public checkers it could be that their checker pretends to be IE6-pre-SP2 so your gzip_disable directives were firing and turning the feature off when the checker made requests.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for everyone's help. I managed to figure it out... (bizarre, still not sure why)

In Ubuntu 9.10, Nginx 0.7.62:

1. I first tried using gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].";  #still broken
2. I then switched it to gzip_disable "msie6"; #still broken
3. I commented out the gzip_disabled line altogether #fixes the problem

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: removing gzip_disabled indeed solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me too. What's odd is that it was actually working for  some resources with gzip_disable. But when I commented out that line, it started working for application/x-javascript resources.

Answer (score 2):

Passenger now compiles the gzip module upon installing nginx. It's much easier to go this route nowadays

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this into `nginx.conf`:

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_comp_level 1;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_types  text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Answer (score 0):

at first here is the description to build nginx on linux

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxInstallOptions

Can you verify that your build support gzip?

```
  --with-http_gzip_static_module
```

Or you didn't build with:

```
--without-http_gzip_module - Disable ngx_http_gzip_module. Requires zlib if enabled.
```

How can you see that the gzip is not working btw.?

Comment: When doing nginx -V:

--with-http_gzip_static does exist.

the http_gzip_module (on-the-fly gzip) isn't disabled.

The package "zlib1g" is installed on the server.

I can tell from looking at the Web Page analyzer tool @ http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze, and also by using http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions from l1x were checked off. Anyone have some ideas? The package was installed using apt-get (so it was pre-compiled)...

Answer (score 0):

Very strange as I just removed the gzip_disable line to resolve my issue.  Maybe this is a bug.  Worked fine in a previous version of nginx that I was running...